# How to use the PIVOT or UNPIVOT T-SQL syntax to achieve this output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have the following table in my SQL Server database.

```
  Mkt    Property    Cat    Description   Values     Date
Germany  JohnS Ltd   SUP    RN             150        JUL 16  
Germany  JohnS Ltd   SUP    RN             100        JUL 16
Germany  JohnS Ltd   DLX    RN              60        JUL 16
Germany  JohnS Ltd   DLX    REV             80        JUL 16
Germany  JohnS Ltd   DLX    REV             75        JUL 16
```

I need my T-SQL query to convert this table (let's call it TblA) and give me the following output:

```
Mkt         Date       Property      Cat      RN     REV
Germany     JUL 16     JohnS Ltd     SUP      250      0
Germany     JUL 16     JohnS Ltd     DLX       60    155
```

I am guessing that I should use either the PIVOT or UNPIVOT syntax to achieve this but I am getting confused with the need to aggregate two values (RN and REV) in a PIVOT query (if that is the right way of doing it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `PIVOT`

```
SELECT  Mkt, Date, Property, Cat, RN, REV
From yourtable
Pivot (sum([Values]) for Description in ([RN],[REV])) pv
```

Considering that number of `Descriptions` is static else you need to use Dynamic Pivot

Comment: There is a missing opening bracket in your solution after the "Pivot" syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Prdp's answer is spot on.  The following is just in case you need to go dynamic

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Description) From YourTable For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Mkt], [Date], [Property], [Cat],' + @SQL + '
  From  YourTable
 Pivot (Sum([Values]) For [Description] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Mkt     Date    Property    Cat   REV   RN
Germany JUL 16  JohnS Ltd   DLX   155   60
Germany JUL 16  JohnS Ltd   SUP   NULL  250
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Pivot :

CREATE TABLE #Details (Mkt VARCHAR(100),  Property VARCHAR(100),    Cat   
 VARCHAR(100),  _Description VARCHAR(100), _Values INT,_Date VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Details ( Mkt,    Property  ,  Cat  ,  _Description ,_Values ,  
_Date)
SELECT 'Germany','JohnS Ltd','SUP','RN',150,'JUL 16' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Germany','JohnS Ltd','SUP','RN',100,'JUL 16' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Germany','JohnS Ltd','DLX','RN',60,'JUL 16' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Germany','JohnS Ltd','DLX','REV',80,'JUL 16' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Germany','JohnS Ltd','DLX','REV',75,'JUL 16' 

SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Mkt,    Property  ,  Cat  ,  _Description ,_Values , _Date
  FROM #Details
)A
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(_Values) FOR _Description IN ([RN],[REV]) 
)pvt
```